# Workaround for Apex switch bug when multiple values and one of them is null?

Tags: apex

The `switch` returns the wrong value for `null` for this case where there are multiple `when` values and one of them is `null` in API 43.0:

```
@IsTest
static void test() {
    // Desired outcomes
    System.assertEquals(1, f('a'));
    System.assertEquals(2, f('b'));
    System.assertEquals(2, f('c'));
    System.assertEquals(3, f('d'));
    System.assertEquals(0, f(''));
    System.assertEquals(0, f(null));        // Fails
}

private static Integer f(String s) {
    // Incorrectly returns 3 for null
    switch on s {
        when null, '' { return 0; }
        when 'a' { return 1; }
        when 'b', 'c' { return 2; }
        when else { return 3; }
    }
}
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I don't suppose you've logged a bug for this? I'm sure @ca_peterson would love to know about this (if he doesn't already).

Comment: @sfdcfox If you mean via a case, sure I'll do that next week unless someone says it is already known.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One workaround is to separate the values. All the asserts pass for this code:

```
private static Integer f(String s) {
    // Correctly returns 0 for null
    switch on s {
        when null { return 0; }
        when '' { return 0; }
        when 'a' { return 1; }
        when 'b', 'c' { return 2; }
        when else { return 3; }
    }
}
```

**PS**

I've reported this bug to Salesforce via case 21246533.

**PPS**

This is now posted as a Salesforce's Known Issue [Null condition in Switch statement not recognized as expected when multiple conditions exist](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=null-condition-in-switch-statement-not-recognized-as-expected-when-multiple-conditions-exist&Id=a1p3A000000BMae) meaning it is likely to be fixed.